# Angular or Typescript strange behaviour

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm facing very strange problem for me. I prepared stackblitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bug-presentation-v2) for this purposes.

What the problem is:

1. Select `Filter Two` from selector
2. Go back to `Filter One` using the same selector
3. Type in `Filter One` input some random values e.g. `123`
4. Press `Test 1` button.

The unexpected behavior is that the input field is cleared. Take a look at implementation how `onTest1` method is implemented and then how `onTest2` method is implemented. When You press `Test 2` button then the input from `Filter One` stays but look at the differences between `onTest1` and `onTest2` implementation. It's only difference in order. In `test1` the value is set to the filter at index 0 and then `null` is set to the filter at index 1.

In `test2` the `null` is set to the filter at index 1 and then value is set to the filter 0.

Can somebody explain this strange behaviour? I'm facing much bigger problem with this and this is only an iceberg for Stackoverflow help purposes. Currently I'm using Angular `5.2.5` and I'm testing on Macbook OSX 10.12.6 with Google Chrome 67.0.3396.99.

Comment: what is the expected behavior? The input is cleared when you are on filter 2 and you click test 2 twice.

Comment: I don't understand why after step 4 the input field `Filter One` is cleared. I'm setting the same value to it as user provided so why it is cleared.

Comment: I commented `this.filters[1].control.setValue(null);` in both click handlers. Now it's not getting cleared. :)

Comment: Heh I know it. Why when I call `setValue(null)` on second filter then it clears first filter too? I have two different instaces of FormControl created - one per filter - so why setting null value on second filter clears also first filter? I don't understand this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using FormControl in a way that's not intended and you've exposed a side effect.

The reason why the bug only appears *after* you selected Filter Two and then go back to Filter One is because that causes the input to subscribe to the second FormControl without unsubscribing to the original control it was bound to.

So the reason the value changes to blank in Test 1 is because first you set filter[0] to the value, then the input element is updated to show the value, then you set filter[1] to null and then the input element is updated to show null.

You should change your code to use NgModel on the input or use Reactive Forms as it is intended.

**Further Explanation**

I checked in GitHub and the issue is in FormControlDirective.  When the @input is changed It calls setupControl from shared and in there it listens to changes on the valueAccessor to udpate the view.  The problem comes because, as far as I can tell, there is no place where some sort of teardown method is called if there was already a value previously set.

**Alternative Approach**

I don't know why you were using FormControl to begin with, but if the filters must be of type FormControl then the simplest thing you could do is the following.

```
<input matInput [ngModel]="selectedFilter.control.value" 
       [ngModelChange]="selectedFilter.control.setValue($event)" />
```

Comment: So Daniel You mean that this is because I'm doing something like this `[formControl]="someDynamicallyChangingFormControl"`?

Comment: Yes.  I've only seen `[formControl]` used in the context of Reactive forms.  You went off the beaten path an encountered a skunk.  Fun question though.

Comment: Is there any other way so I can select from array of `FormControl` with different validation rules etc and use it on one input element?

Comment: There should be, but I don't do enough with Reactive Forms to give the best answer.  Maybe ngFor each filter and display an input bound to the FormControl.  Only show the one visible one with an *ngIf comparing to the value of a drop down of all filters.  Shouldn't be that much different come to think of it.

Comment: Your investigation was really helpful. I will try to reorganise template with *ngFor. Good idea btw... Thanks a lot

Comment: Haha it works. Now I feel that I need to make huge refactor in my project. I'm more aware how it works now thanks to You. Take a look at the template changes here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/bug-presentation-v3